# Grails Where is the index() function in a controller get called?

Tags: grails, gsp

In a grails proj, I have a file called LineLeaderController.groovy. Inside it have a function like below which returns a map.

```
def index() {
  Map allData = [:]
  // more code here
  return allData
}
```

How can I know which file is calling this function index()?
While I tried debug, after this function run through, the allData being populated to a gsp file called _tool_preview.gsp. I even tried to search whole project for this keyword index() function, but I doesn't find any relevent result. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The index action is the default action for a controller. For example, assume the following controller handles all URLs that match the pattern `/foo/*`

```
class FooController {    
  def index() {}
  def bar() {}
}
```

If a request is made to `/foo/bar` it will invoke the `bar` action, but if a request is made to just `/foo/`, `index` will be invoked because it's the default action. The trailing backslash is optional, so `index` will also handle a request to `/foo`.

The above assumes you're using the default URL mappings. In your application these may be overridden in the file `grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy`.